# Worfklow's editor user cannot edit content items

Tags: sitecore-client, workflow

I have created a custom workflow with four steps and created three roles to access the website, editor, reviewer and publisher.

I gave every user the proper role and needed permissions, however the user cannot edit any item under the content tree and all fields look grey out.

[image]

below is how the role's permissions are set

[image]

Can you help?

Comment: Are you sure the items in question are not marked "Protected"?

Comment: No, they are not protected, I already set read, write permissions for content items under the tree

Comment: I have a similar issue, but my solution is not based on Habitat. Any ideas how it can be fixed without adding Habitat's roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add Habitat roles to the membership of the users,

[image]

After adding the required roles, I was able to edit and modify content items normally

Answer (score 2):

When you assign a workflow to an item, the user must have some special rights for the workflow too, not only for the item.
In your case, to be able to edit the item, your editor must have "Workflow state write" for the current state of the item to be able to edit the item.
[image]

### Sitecore defines three workflow specific access rights.

- Workflow State Delete — controls whether or not a user can delete items which are currently associated with a specific workflow state
- Workflow State Write controls whether or not a user can update items which are currently associated with a specific workflow state.
- Workflow Command Execute — controls whether or not a user is shown
  specific workflow commands.

Extracted from section 3.4 of this old but still valid [document](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/workflowreference-usletter.pdf)

Comment: I have already set permissions for delete, execute actions on the workflow states as you described above however still unable to edit the content fields. the strange is that I can create and rename content items and every checkbox and rich text box seem to be dimmed but editable where i can modify its data!

Comment: In what state the item is? Is it locked by somebody else?

Comment: it's in the draft state and is only locked by the editor user who cannot access the content item.